# Generate SQL server scripts from command line?

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, scripting, wizard, ssms

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 there is a "Generate scripts..." option under the Tasks menu. I'm just wondering if this tool is available from the command line somehow?

[image: Screenshot of Generate SQL Server Scripts Wizard]

It looks similar to the sqlpubwiz.exe command line tool that was available for SQL Server 2005, but I can't find this executable anywhere in the SQL 2008 installation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The script generating options of Management Studio are just a wrapper around the [SMO scripting capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162153.aspx). Simple scripts are obtained by using the `Script()` method on various SMO types. More complex scripts are created by the specialized [`Scripter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx) class.

Command line tools can be easily created by using the SMO libraries.

Answer (score 7):

The SQLPubWiz.Exe for SQL2008 R2 on my PC is located on "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Publishing\1.4"

Comment: I think the "90" indicates that you're actually accessing the SQL Server *2005* directory.

Comment: This works great, thanks ! However, for SQL 2008 you need to specify the option: -targetserver 2008

Answer (score 5):

You can use mssql-scripter, a command line tool that generates T-SQL scripts for databases and database objects (works on Windows, macOS, and Linux).

The download for mssql-scripter is via pip as it is Python-based:
pip install mssql-scripter

You'll run a command similar to the following to script the database schema and data to a file:
$ mssql-scripter -S localhost -d AdventureWorks -U sa --schema-and-data  > ./adventureworks.sql
More usage examples: https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-xplat-cli/blob/dev/doc/usage_guide.md

This project can be found at this GitHub repo - https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-xplat-cli

Answer (score 3):

SQLPUBWIZ SCRIPT -d yourDBName -S yourServerName -U userName -P userPassword scriptFilewithPath

Download for SQL2005 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A