# Can sqlcmd be used to dump table structure and data?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

Is it possible to use the sqlcmd command to dump table structure the way it can be done with mysqldump?

Comment: Duplicate question is answered nicely here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309822/generate-sql-server-scripts-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

You would need to load on a stored procedure first.  The one I keep going back to is:

http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code.htm#inserts

I owe the guy that made it a couple of pints as it has saved me a load of hassle over the years.

Comment: This is a good tip.  Unfortunately it won't work in this case because I don't have permissions to install a stored procedure on the source database.

Comment: Note this linked stored procedure only dumps the data INSERTs; it doesn't generate table CREATE statements.